# how set new variable in camunda from non delegate class

Tags: java, camunda, camunda-modeler

I know that I can get process instance by

```
 ProcessInstance processInstance = runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery()
      .variableValueEquals("tour_id", id)
      .singleResult();
```

but how can I add new variable in processInstance in non delegate java class?

Answer (score 1):

I found how can I do that.

```
runtimeService.setVariableLocal(processInstance.getId(), "varKey", "varValue");
```